# Creating and Updating with has_many: through in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm having quite a bit of trouble with assigning `has_many: through` in Rails 4.

I have a functioning `has_many: through` with the table `products` and `programs` joined at the table `program_products`.  My models are functioning correctly, as `Product.programs = Program.all` successfully assigns `programs` to my `products`.  However, I cannot figure out how to gain that functionality in the view.

I've read that the most common way is with a `collection_check_boxes`, so I devised the following in my form view:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:programs, Program.all, :id, :name ) %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This gives me HTML output of

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="product[programs][]" id="product_programs_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="product[programs][]" id="product_programs_2">
```

and so on.

When I submit my form, I get this response in the params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xxx",
 "product"=>{"name"=>"Test",
 "description"=>"desc test",
 "price"=>"10",
 "programs"=>["1",
 "2",
 "3",
 ""]},
 "commit"=>"Update Product",
 "id"=>"18"}
```

With no errors.  However, my database never actually updates, so I can't figure out what's going wrong.  Here are the important bits of my controllers:

**products_controller.rb (main CRUD controller)**

```
def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
        redirect_to(pages_dashboard_path)
    end
end
```

---

```
  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price, :programs)
  end
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong, since I'm not getting any outright errors.  The documentation for collection_check_boxes on Rails is rather confusing, so I suspect that my error may lie in that setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `program_ids` instead of `programs` in your `collection_check_boxes` call. And make sure to change that in the permition method as well.

Comment: Seems to have fixed something!  I did what you said, and now I can read correctly (i.e. the products I manually set the programs of now show up as filled in when I click them).  However, I still seem to be having trouble writing changes.  I'll do some experimenting.  Edit - got it!  had to do `:program_ids => []` instead of just `:program_ids` in the permit.  Thanks!